# Redhat: Enabling proxy for specific IP addresses only

Tags: linux, redhat, proxy, http-proxy

I have a server that ordinarily does not require a proxy to connect (e.g.) to any URL on the internet. However some specific systems (IP addresses) I need to connect to via a specific proxy.

My question is how I can specify the proxy per IP-Address / subnet without disrupting the normal configuration where no proxy is required.

I am aware of the following variables that can be set, however this operates on an exclusion basis to access the proxy rather than an inclusion basis:

```
export http_proxy=http://my-proxy.tld:8080
export https_proxy=https://my-proxy.tld:8080
export no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,192.168.1.123, ...
```

The server in question is a RedHat V7.1 box.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: What are the nature of the applications you're talking about? One-shot CLI utilities? Long-running daemons? Etc.? If long-running daemons, how are the services being started?

Comment: These are daemons which are running, so long-running services. They have been started using systemctl. For example, a LAMP stack is in use amongst other services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Squid. If you want a smaller footprint installation and smaller configuration files, you could also try Tinyproxy.

Comment: Interesting, yes. I was hoping for a solution available within the OS without the need to run a proxy-server on the same box.

Comment: you could run the `http_proxy=xy | abc` which should only set it for this command

Comment: additional I've found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/set-a-network-range-in-the-no-proxy-environment-variable